# How come an INNER JOIN returns zero rows when I use coalesce?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CPC.importe
FROM fac_factura FAC 
INNER JOIN fac_concepto_periodo_control CPC ON CPC.id_factura = FAC.id
INNER JOIN fac_factura_deuda_pendiente FDP ON FDP.id_factura = FAC.id
INNER JOIN fac_item_facturacion FIF ON CPC.id_item_facturacion = FIF.id
WHERE FIF.codigo = 427
AND FDP.estado ILIKE 'CANCELADA'
AND CPC.estado ILIKE 'FACTURADO'
```

The column named `importe` is numeric but the `JOIN` conditions are not being fulfilled so it returns a blank value instead of a `NULL` mark.

How can I set this value to `0` instead of a blank value, I tried with `COALESCE` but it's not working.

Comment: Can you add the definitions of the tables and one example where this happens? In theory, it's not possible. You may get *no rows*, if the `JOIN` conditions produce *no rows*, which is different from *blank*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The column named importe is numeric but the JOIN conditions are not being fulfilled so it returns a blank value instead of a NULL mark.
>
> How can I set this value to 0 instead of a blank value, I tried with COALESCE but it's not working.

If the join conditions are *not* being fulfilled you have 0-rows. An INNER JOIN on false returns 0-rows: not one row with a null value, not one row with a zero.

```
SELECT x,y
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
JOIN ( VALUES (2) ) AS g(y)
  ON false;
 x | y 
---+---
(0 rows)
```

Returns nothing. What you want is an outer join.

```
SELECT x,y
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( VALUES (2) ) AS g(y)
  ON false;
 x | y 
---+---
 1 |  
(1 row)
```

Now that you have a row, you can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT x, coalesce(y,0) AS y
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( VALUES (2) ) AS g(y)
  ON false;
 x | y 
---+---
 1 | 0
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about that conditions on `joins`. It helped me a lot! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm that your Data Grid settings do not convert NULL values to blank text.  TOAD for Oracle does this by default, and I always have to set it back whenever I install on a new machine.

If you want to force a 0 when you get NULL values, you may want to try COUNT(importe).  Be weary, as this only works when you're wanting ONE result.  It is NOT a substitute for COALESCE, IFNULL, NVL, etc.

```
SELECT COUNT(CPC.importe)
FROM fac_factura FAC
```